# Where is the Error in my C++ code?

Tags: c++, crash

Here is the error screenshot: http://prntscr.com/9n6ybt

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)
    {
        if (b%i==0)
        {
            cout << i << " ";
        }
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `a <= 0`, something modulo 0 is computed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not handling the case where i might be 0 (division by 0) so b % i is indetermined. You can solve it by going this way:

```
if (i==0) continue;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)
{
    if (b%i==0)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

Will give a **division by zero** if `i == 0`.

You'll have to check the input, or the value of `i`, for example:

```
for(int i=a; i<=b; i++)
{
    if (i > 0 && b%i==0)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

If `i == 0`, `b%i==0` will not be evaluated.

Comment: Oh, totally forgot on that one!

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the case division by "zero". When the value of i = 0 then the code fails and produce an exception.
You should do like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   int a, b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)
    {   if (i == 0)
             continue;
        else if (b%i == 0)
             cout << i << " ";

    }   
    return 0;
}
```